# Views + Page Title translation

Tags: views, i18n-l10n, 7

This is *not* a question about how I translate the View's (display) title.

My scenario is that I have a views **without** a title, and use the [Page Title](http://drupal.org/project/page_title) module to still have a title for SEO.
The problem is that this title does not seem to be translatable.

I have looked at the [hooks](https://drupal.org/node/1204018) that are made available by the Page Title module, but they don't seem to get me where I want to go with this.

Can anyone suggest an approach to be able to solve this?

Comment: Did you look at this issue?: https://drupal.org/node/1695020

Comment: You can write your own custom module and use [`drupal_set_title()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/drupal_set_title/7) if you don't want to cooperate in the module's issue queue.

Comment: @xurshid29's issue link got me somewhat further, but I misunderstood the problem and need something else.

I'm going to leave this question as is though in hope of an answer for people who might need this in the future.

Comment: @Jeroen That issue requires a little bit knowledge of using Variable API. I didn't mention that it will exactly help you. You can get a logic from that issue.